# Object validation has failed. Sales Invoice: Object validation has failed. You cannot delete this invoice

Tags: custom-object, delete

How can I delete an Invoice?  I have already created a permission set that enables me to do so but it still doesn't seem to enable a delete.  When I try to delete, I get the following error.

"Object validation has failed. Sales Invoice: Object validation has failed. You cannot delete this invoice."

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any custom validation rules on the object? How about triggers?

Comment: There are no validation rules on the Invoice object.  It does have some triggers attached.

Comment: Try capturing the debug log when the delete fails. It may indicate what is causing the problem.

Comment: I've tried that already.  I appreciate the idea though.

Comment: Does the error appear in the debug log? I'd be surprised if there wasn't any indication of what was occurring in the log. Or at least a small clue. Can you include some of the last lines of the log in the question?

Another course of action would be to temporarily disable the triggers.